# Pimcore Install fails due to non-resovlvable set of packages

Tags: php, installation, pimcore

I fail to install Pimcore. When following https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Getting_Started/Installation.html I get the following error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- pimcore/pimcore[v10.5.0, ..., 10.6.x-dev] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
- Root composer.json requires pimcore/pimcore ^10.5 -> satisfiable by pimcore/pimcore[v10.5.0, ..., 10.6.x-dev].

- I DO HAVE gd installed and enabled
- I'm running on WSL2
- I'm on php 8.16
- Apache 2.4

Bye

Michael

Answer (score -1):

By now you probably already have solved this, but for anyone else who is going through this, I would recommend using the docker containers provided by Pimcore. They contain everything that is required to run a pimcore application so that later on you don't have to worry about something not working because it is not installed on your machine.

Since there already is a `docker-compose.yml` file provided with pimcore. You just need to make sure that docker and docker-compose are installed in your host machine. Then, all you got to do is clone the right pimcore version, open the directory and run `docker-compose up -d` and voila. Everything should work!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34695315)